# Hide folder from search in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to exclude a folder from search in Sublime Text 3 but not in sidebar.

**folder_exclude_patterns:** hides folder from Search and Goto Anything but also in sidebar

**binary_file_patterns:** hides from Goto Anything but not from Search.

Is there any trick to do this?

```
"folder_exclude_patterns":
[
    "node_modules"
],

"binary_file_patterns":
[
    "node_modules/"
],
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me if you don't want to remove them from the side bar, but remove it from the search index

```
{
  "folders":
  [
    {
      "path": "my/path",
      "folder_exclude_patterns":[],
      "binary_file_patterns":["node_modules/*"],
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice I am using the **/***